# Passing security certificates using requests

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I need to access a site, but I am getting an error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

**Code**:

```
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://www.portfolio123.com/"
r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'server_status.jsp')
```

**Full Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 352, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.portfolio123.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /server_status.jsp (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lakewealth/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 5, in <module>
    r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'server_status.jsp')
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.portfolio123.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /server_status.jsp (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

There are a lot of questions on this subject such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369633/adding-server-certificates-to-ca-bundle-in-python), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982143/python-requests-how-to-use-system-ca-certificates-debian-ubuntu/42982144). I scanned through them, but didn't find the solution yet.

```
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://www.portfolio123.com/"
CERT = 'c:\data\P123.CER'
r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'server_status.jsp', verify=CERT)
```

Comment: I contacted the site owner and they fixed it. But the question stands.

Comment: Have you tried verify=False?

Comment: @proton `verify=false` "works" in that it disables verification, but it creates a security vulnerability for man in the middle attacks.